# Swift - UIImage filter triggering exception

Tags: ios, swift, nsunknownkeyexception

I followed an online tutorial that helps in creating a QR code. My objective is that the QR code created will be stored in Parse DB as a file and locally in a userObject as UIImage. When I ran my code below, it triggered the following error:

> 2015-12-06 12:43:45.994 Mawq[7246:279805] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputImage.'

The code to create the QR code I used is:

```
print("1")
let data = userObject.username!.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
print("2")
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
print("3")
filter!.setValue(data, forKey: "QRImage")
print("4")
let newQRImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter!.outputImage!);
print("5")
user["qrCode"] = newQRImage;
print("6")
userObject.userQRCode = newQRImage;
print("7")
```

The print statements are just to know where the error is triggered. Apparently as shown in console, it is after line 3 prints it goes wrong. The tutorial I followed is here: http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-generator-tutorial/.

The userObject where I want to store the image is as follows:

```
public class UserClass {

    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var password: String?
    var mobile: String?
    var username: String?
    var tempToken: Int?
    var userQRCode: UIImage?
}
```

This is my first time to use the UIKit to achieve this outcome...so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the filter variable nil after you have created it using CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")?

Comment: What is `filter!.setValue(data, forKey: "QRImage")` supposed to do? It is not listed in the tutorial.

Comment: @luk2302 it is in the tutorial as filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

Comment: yes, do you see the difference??? `"QRImage" != "inputMessage"` !!!!!

Comment: @andlin after an if condition was added, it is not nil.

Comment: Upvote for: `"QRImage" != "inputMessage"` :)

Comment: @luk2302 ok changed that to filter!.setValue(data, forKey: userObject.username!) since I want the username to be the data converted to QR. it is still triggering the same error

Comment: The key **must be** `"inputMessage"`. You need to use the key the filter will accept.

Comment: @ksa_coder read up on key-value coding, you cannot just input new keys, how is that supposed to work? You have to change the **VALUE**, not the key.

Comment: ok got it now. Thanks for clarifying it...got confused there for a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the same code that was used in the tutorial:

```
filter!.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
```

while `data` holds the data that you want to the QR code image to hold. For example the username:

```
let data = userObject.username!.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

Thats all you have to do. **DO NOT** change the key.

What is used here for setting different values of the filter is called key-value-coding, you input arbitrary values for specific keys. The filter than reads values of some keys and interprets and evaluates them. The set of keys is fixed. The filter expects a `inputMessage` to be present. The filter however does *not* expect a `QRImage` to be passed in.